# Number Chaining Predicate

Tags: code-golf

## Problem:

Your task is to decide if in a sequence of numbers, every number contains at least one of the digits of the number that preceded it.

For example, the following should return truthy:

```py
[1, 12, 203, 0, 30]
             ^   ^ Contains a 0
        ^ Contains a 2
    ^ Contains a 1
```

The following should return falsey:

```py
[1, 32, 23, 34]
    ^ Doesn't contain a 1, therefore false
```

Your submission can be a function or full program.

## Input:

Input can be any reasonable type of sequence. An array of numbers, an array of strings, a delimited string of numbers, etc.

Order matters however, so whatever structure you choose to accept as input obviously must have a definite ordering.

Input can be taken via the stdin or as an argument.

You can assume:

- all numbers will be non-negative integers
- input will always contain at least 2 numbers
- input numbers will not start with a 0

## Output:

Output will be a truthy or falsey value (as defined by your language), representing whether or not the above specification is met.

Truthy/falsey values don't need to be consistent between tests.

It can either be output to the stdout or returned.

## Test Cases:

```py
True cases:
[1, 1, 1, 11, 111, 11, 1]
[12, 23, 34, 45, 56]
[65, 54, 43, 32, 21]
[123, 29, 9, 59, 55, 52, 2017, 2]
[1234567890, 19, 95, 5012, 23]

False cases:
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 11] (2 doesn't contain a 1)
[12, 23, 33, 45] (45 doesn't contain a 3)
[98, 87, 76, 11, 12, 23] (11 doesn't contain a 7 or 6)
```

This is code-golf, so the least number of bytes wins.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>5</s> 4 bytes

```
f2\Ạ
```

Input is an array of strings.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/jelly#XU45DsJADOx5xTzAQknI5qgpeERIgdByFCQosZDoEA2foOAB9BwFDS8JHwk2WSiQ7LV3ZuSZdhaMm/upbW6P1/7cFZ4Ht4zQXC@v3RHDstjYisElaq6WxbwmrCZrlIKCFxZsa8Z0Ulsh1pVl3spYFtxv2yzLfIKrT3@XnHpA5geEYEAYhITQEEzU4ZHuiimnmp9egCAlSBlt1Snv@bG8P1FoojhJPfFRrYq8zioXSQ@fVPKXY2JiXLy/SEqaDksTQiIGceTSu1v5Gw)

#### How it works

```
f2\Ạ  Main link. Argument: A (array of strings)

 2\   Pairwise reduce by:
f       Filter, yielding all chars in the left string that appear in the right one.
   Ạ  All; yield 1 if all strings are non-empty, 0 if not.
```

Answer (score 13):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 48 bytes

```python
lambda x:reduce(lambda a,b:set(a)&set(b)and b,x)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/python2#bY9NboMwEIX3nMKrGkuuxJ@BIGXbE3RHUWPAViylTgRGysWzJniGJEjp5o3H8z7NG73/mU/yr@0luVaD6qdOhWsveVuNyoWSffjSMml70vIrm92vU6PjGsre2MvkQhZcBmMdod/DpIgfjDTQ54EYYixBogoImgw/6NCww4P5kqfxHdL/Q3Nd1zSmnGxl1W1DG774Ev9OUq9p5jUTXkUO4xwbHKAJgQcNf8nOK4hARQytUVxABSJakEzkRQm@GEF0R88szeJcT4AvWAIZxPait/zpmt8PdqVvSlhd5JuzX0ua@WbPn53sjuoO)

Print a empty set for `False` and the last element for `True`

Answer (score 12):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina), <s>25</s> 20 bytes

```
(.).*¶(?=.*\1)

^.+$
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/retina#NY1bCgIxDEX/sw6FzngpTdv08THMIvwVcZUuwI3V24okJOEcuLm6@wvD@c3vn7c7D78/dBN5@ttlDMWq2b8lGhETUkY2WJHCyZuEfNqE2NFhbCrCoBVRAk22UluH0lOFlSSKiIQMW3/@8SQmvaFV1LIeT/4F)

Whenever we find a digit that also occurs in the next number, we remove the separator between those numbers (along with the digits in the former number, starting from the shared one, but that's irrelevant). The input is valid, if all separators have been remove in the process, which we check by making sure that the string can be matched as a single line.

Answer (score 11):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 9 bytes

```
{⊇ᵐ=∧?t}ˡ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/brachylog2#@1/9qKv94dYJto86ltuX1J5e@P9/tKGOoZGOkYGxjoGOsUHs/695@brJickZqQA)

Note that this not only works with a list of integers, but also with a list of strings or a list of lists.

#### Explanation

```
{      }ˡ       Left fold on the input:
 ⊇ᵐ=              It is possible to find a number which is a subset of both input numbers
    ∧             (and)
     ?t           The output is the second number (to continue the fold)
```

Comment: That's cool. Seems... declarative? Reads like you're just telling the language the specification.

Comment: @Carcigenicate Brachylog is indeed declarative, it is based on the declarative logic programming language [Prolog](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prolog).

Comment: Prologs actually on my (increasingly) long list of languages to learn when I attain unlimited free time. There's too many cool languages!

Answer (score 8):

## JavaScript (ES6), <s>47</s> <s>44<sup><sub>*</sub></sup></s> 43 bytes

*Saved a byte thanks to @Neil*

```
x=>x.every(y=>y.match(`[${p}]`,p=y),p=1/19)
```

Takes input as a list of strings.

#### Test snippet

```js
let f =
x=>x.every(y=>y.match(`[${p}]`,p=y),p=1/19)

let g = x => console.log("f([%s]): %s", x.join(", "), f(x.map(String)))

g([1, 1, 1, 11, 111, 11, 1])
g([12, 23, 34, 45, 56])
g([65, 54, 43, 32, 21])
g([123, 29, 9, 59, 55, 52, 2017, 2])
g([123456789, 19, 95, 5012, 23])

g([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 11])
g([12, 23, 33, 45])
g([98, 87, 76, 11, 12, 23])
```

*<sub>*([crossed out 44 is still regular 44](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7427/42963))*</sub>

Comment: Does `\`[${p}]\`` not work?

Comment: @Neil Not for the first item of each array.

Comment: Ah, I see you found a workaround. I had got as far as `a=>a.reduce((l,r)=>\`${l}\`.match(\`[${r}]\`)&&r)` (which also works for numeric input).

Comment: Perhaps you can remove the `p&&` if you set `p=1/19`?

Comment: @Neil I, uh... well... That's genius, thanks :-)

Comment: The `1/19` trick is really cool. However, a simpler `'^x'` would work just as well (same size, though).

Answer (score 6):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 10 bytes

```
ü‚vy`Så1åP
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/05ab1e#@394z6OGWWWVCcGHlxoeXhrw/3@0oY4CFIExjBELAA)
or as a [Test suite](https://tio.run/nexus/05ab1e#TY5NCsIwEIX3nmKI2xGaNH/1FIIIhVDwFIWCgudw31sIXeQmXiS@MRGEmWTy3sfL3OZFpYnVYX8ZS369H895uZ7zqvN6KvdR5e1IeVNckmZq9e3fMO2SNkymZ@otk3VMzkP0MogghgCVxMsMTCgnLZCYnQ44QXRArPMhwtUCCtHVHyQAN/IQC7lt87@BOA7CEJkiIoNva9aADw)

**Explanation**

```
ü‚          # map pairing over each pair in input
  v         # for each pair
   y`       # push as 2 separate elements on stack
     Så     # check each digit in 2nd number for membership in first
       1å   # check if any 1 exists in the resulting list
         P  # product of stack
```

Comment: `€Sü.å` - I wish this worked like I thought it would.

Comment: @carusocomputing: Yeah that would have been great. Or just `ü.å` or `€Süå`.

Comment: Why doesn't pairwise work with dot commands again?

Comment: @carusocomputing: It's only implemented to take the next byte as command. It doesn't take the dot into account.

Answer (score 6):

## [CJam](https://sourceforge.net/p/cjam), <s>18</s> <s>15</s> 14 bytes

*Saved 4 bytes thanks to Martin Ender*

```
l~Afb_1>.&:,:*
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/cjam#@59T55iWFG9op6dmpWOl9f9/tKGRgpGxgrGJgomxqYKpWSwA)

**Explanation**

```
l~              e# Read and eval the input
  Afb           e# Convert each number to a list of digits
     _          e# Duplicate the array
      1>        e# Slice it after the first element
        .&      e# Vectorized set intersection; take the set intersection of corresponding 
                e#  elements of the two arrays
          :,    e# Get the length of each intersection
            :*  e# Take the product of the whole array. 
                e#  Will be 0 if any intersection was empty.
```

Answer (score 6):

## Haskell, <s>51</s> <s>48</s> 35 Bytes

-3 bytes thanks to @NickHansen! I really need to get better with those monad operators

-4 and -9 bytes thanks to @Laikoni and @nimi respectively!

```
and.(zipWith(any.flip elem)=<<tail)
```

This version takes the input as an array of strings, eliminating the need for `show`, but as far as I can see it works in largely the same way as the older version:

```
all(\(x,y)->any(`elem`x)y).(zip=<<tail).map show
```

(I'm fairly certain I'm allowed to submit an anonymous function like this, but I'll fix it if necessary)

First the numbers are converted to strings. Then the monad magic `zip=<<tail` creates a function that zips the list with itself which pairs each entry with its neighbor(s). Then `all` maps a lambda to each pair that checks whether one string contains any chars from the other and finally checks that they all come out `True`.

Old version that works basically the same way:

```
f a=and$zipWith(\b->any(`elem`show b).show)a$tail a
```

Comment: I was able to shave a byte by using zip and some (->) monad trickery: f(x,y)=any('elem'x)y;g=all f.(zip=<<tail).map show . edit: elem should [hopefully obviously] be in backticks but that isn't possible with the comment formatter.

Comment: 44 bytes: `and.(zipWith(any.flip elem)=<<tail).map show`

Comment: It's allowed to take the input as a list of strings, e.g. `["1234567890", "19", "95", "5012", "23"]`, so you can drop the `.map show`.

Answer (score 5):

## Ruby, <s>49</s> 48 bytes

```
->x{x.each_cons(2){|z|x&&=z*' '=~/(.).* .*\1/};x}
```

Output is `nil` for false and a "random" integer for true.

Answer (score 5):

## Mathematica <s>62 47</s> 35 bytes

With 12 bytes saved thanks to MartinE.

```
FreeQ[#⋂#2&@@@Partition[#,2,1],{}]&
```

---

```
FreeQ[#⋂#2&@@@Partition[#,2,1],{}]&[{{1},{1,2},{2,0,3},{0},{3,1}}]
```

> False

```
FreeQ[#⋂#2&@@@Partition[#,2,1],{}]&[{{1},{1,2},{2,0,3},{0},{3,0}}]
```

> True

Answer (score 4):

## Java 8, <s>94</s> <s>90</s> 87 bytes

Input is an array of strings representing the numbers. Starting with the second string, it performs a regular expression comparison against each previous string to see if it contains any of its characters: `.*[previous string].*`.

Golfed:

```java
a->{int r=1,i=0;while(++i<a.length)r*=a[i].matches(".*["+a[i-1]+"].*")?1:0;return r>0;}
```

Ungolfed:

```java
public class NumberChainingPredicate {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Expect true:");
    for (String[] input : new String[][] { { "1", "1", "1", "11", "111", "11", "1" }, { "12", "23", "34", "45", "56" },
        { "65", "54", "43", "32", "21" }, { "123", "29", "9", "59", "55", "52", "2017", "2" },
        { "1234567890", "19", "95", "5012", "23" } }) {
      System.out.println(java.util.Arrays.toString(input) + " = " + exec(f(), input));
    }

    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("Expect false:");
    for (String[] input : new String[][] { { "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "1", "11" }, { "12", "23", "33", "45" },
        { "98", "87", "76", "11", "12", "23" } }) {
      System.out.println(java.util.Arrays.toString(input) + " = " + exec(f(), input));
    }
  }

  private static java.util.function.Function<String[], Boolean> f() {
    return a -> {
      int r = 1, i = 0;
      while (++i < a.length) {
        r *= a[i].matches(".*[" + a[i - 1] + "].*") ? 1 : 0;
      }
      return r > 0;
    };
  }

  private static boolean exec(java.util.function.Function<String[], Boolean> function, String[] input) {
    return function.apply(input);
  }

}
```

Comment: Nice! A lot shorter than I was about to post.. Anyway, you can golf some more: `a->{for(int i=1;i<a.length;)if(!a[i].matches(".*["+a[i++-1]+"].*"))return 0>1;return 1>0;}` (**90 bytes**)

Comment: I also golfed it to 90, but in a different way: `a->{int r=1;for(int i=0;++i<a.length;)r*=a[i].matches(".*["+a[i-1]+"].*")?1:0;return r>0;}`

Comment: Nevermind, got it to 87: `a->{int r=1,i=0;for(;++i<a.length;)r*=a[i].matches(".*["+a[i-1]+"].*")?1:0;return r>0;}`

Comment: Thanks to both of you. I think the only way to improve this by a meaningful amount now is to look at the regex.

Answer (score 4):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 6 bytes

```
Dµf"ḊẠ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/jelly#@@9yaGua0sMdXQ93Lfj//3@0oZGxjpGxiY6pgYmOgY6JgamZjqmZuY65gY5BLAA)

### Explanation

```
Dµf"ḊẠ
Dµ        Treat the first (i.e. only) input as a list of decimal digits
   "      For each pair of corresponding elements in {the input digits} and
    Ḋ     {the input digits} with the first element removed
  f       take all elements common to both sides
     Ạ    then return true if the result has no empty lists, false otherwise
```

It's most obvious to try to use `2/` here, but that runs a unary function on all slices of size 2. `"Ḋ` effectively runs a *binary* function on all pairs of adjacent elements, which means we can use `f` directly (rather than needing to convert it to a unary function as `f/`). This does end up leaving the last element of the input in place, but luckily not even an input of 0 becomes an empty list when converted to decimal, so it has no effect on the `Ạ`.

Answer (score 4):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 48 bytes

```python
f=lambda x:x==x[:1]or{*x[0]}&{*x[1]}and f(x[1:])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/python3#XU/LCoNADDzrV@RUXMnBVdcX@B/Cdg8WEYT6wHpYKH67TerWQyHZTTJDZnL09bMdH10LtrJ1bXUlzby@Q6sjs9/4l2Zvpw76gMrKiKOfV2hgmODug9ZaIrj45q8w6ANoGSPECUKSIqQKQWXnPOOaZ4wx5@LTIC4RKBQn8xiPZE7vRUpVlhdlRDrMZVJ0ShmisC2yQD0tIxHl7P1ZYlCds7JAKEggz5x7t8tUvsfnWj63ocZb1mHagj7Q4dguwWtb0QojhO8AcXwA)

Answer (score 3):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 8 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
Dœ&L¥2\Ạ
```

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/jelly#@@9ydLKaz6GlRjEPdy34//9/tKGOgrGRjoKRMZA2iQUA)**

#### How?

```
Dœ&L¥2\Ạ - Main link: the list of integers            e.g. [3, 13, 351, 73, 82]
D        - convert all the integers to decimal lists       [[3],[1,3],[3,5,1],[7,3],[8,2]]
     2\  - 2-slice cumulative reduce with:
    ¥    -     last two links as a dyad:
 œ&      -         multiset intersection                   [[3],[1,3],[3],[]]
         -         length                                  [1,2,1,0]
       Ạ - all truthy?                                     0
```

Answer (score 3):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 5 bytes

Code:

```
üÃõå_
```

Uses the **CP-1252** encoding. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/05ab1e#@394z@Hmw1sPL43//z/a0EhHwchYR8EYiE1MYwE) or [Verify all test cases!](https://tio.run/nexus/05ab1e#TY7LEcMgDETvqUIF6AAY8SnAacKTSSU5uRaX4JtvFEZ2A57JjARi982i8pS1t6vt7WzHu6t8@uZVZv36Hl6PzQeVsKgsUSWaiiWIiQMFGgQGiVeoKihjE6LpfMY5iGgpl@qQTZCEGz/Qxo08xEKe2/xvQMcg1KJSEJnTXHMEfAE).

Explanation:

```
üÃ         # Intersection on each pair
  õå       # Check if the empty string exists
    _      # Boolean negate
```

Comment: Oh man it DOES work! `RüÃõå_` was what I came up with on my own. I'm honored to have been so close to your best answer, deleting mine. Why do you not need the `R` though?

Comment: @carusocomputing Hmmm, what is the `R` for then? :p

Answer (score 2):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), 87 bytes

```powershell
param($n)(1..($a=$n.length-1)|?{[char[]]$n[($i=$_)-1]|?{$n[$i]-like"*$_*"}}).count-eq$a
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/powershell#FcjRCoMgGIbhe4kP1JiC1Q6jCxGJn5Alq39L6qi6dudOHnjf/KVEqwQraY2RoB5slsCvfdZWXcPpppmS8x7sJGKPUWnryy@N6PUS36GqMdbVfSszfQ7eddhAOWdhG/EQTVto/3RP8QM)

Not the shortest by any measure, but a slightly different approach than others are using, and shows off the nifty `|?{}` functionality.

This takes the input as an array of strings into `$n`, then loops from `1` up to the `length-1`. We use `Where-Object` (the `|?{...}`) to pull out those indices that are truthy for a particular condition. You can think of this like a combination `for` loop with an `if` clause.

The clause here is `[char[]]$n[($i=$_)-1]|?{$n[$i]-like"*$_*"}`. That is, we're taking the current index `$_`, setting it to `$i`, and subtracting `1`, and using that to index into `$n` (i.e., so we get the previous element in our input array). That is then cast as a `char`-array and sent through another `Where-Object` procedure.

The inner clause `$n[$i]-like"*$_*"` specifies that the string at the current index `$i` is `-like` the current character `$_` from the previous index. This will therefore output any characters that are in common between the two array elements. Thus, the outer clause will only be truthy if there is a character in common (since an empty array is falsey in PowerShell), and so the index will only be selected if there are characters in common.

Then, we gather up all of the indices that matched the criteria, and verify that the `.count` thereof is `-eq`ual to the length of the input array. That Boolean result is left on the pipeline, and output is implicit.

Answer (score 2):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 31 bytes

A port of Martin Ender's beautiful [answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/112950/55508).

30 bytes of code + `-p` flag.

```perl
s/(\S)\S* (?=\S*\1)//g;$_=!/ /
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/perl5#NY3RCoMwDEXf/Yo79UE3ttpqW4vIPsJXQWSUjc1N0fr9LnWMhNxwDiTRYbLzgPO0LSxpm7RtjkiuNUXLU8buVdzVBwa2@SXJTnGXXsL2E1aI8FwXBzfi3b8s3MNiXN20OtwG28923jj28v2LgAuIHHmBQkKqQNGknQhxb3MIAwNJTYpgxjWEF4VUujQZOHlS2X4p4BDIUUDuf/7nicigNCg1tNofe/4F)

Answer (score 2):

## PHP, <strike>65</strike> 68

```
for(;null!==$a=$argv[++$i+1];)$r+=$a==strtr($a,$argv[$i],_);echo!$r;
```

iterate over all numbers and remove all digits that appeared in the previous. Count how often it equals the number itself (no digit removed). If at least one equaled we didn't have a match in one of the pairs.

---

Fixed a mistake using `trim` insted of `strtr`. Thanks to @JörgHülsermann

Comment: A big Sorry. for the given testcases your solution works. `["filename",1,11,414]` works not.

Comment: @JörgHülsermann sure `trim` only works for the leading and trailing chars. Fixed it.

Comment: For PHP<7.1, you can use `a&` instead of `null!==` (-5 bytes).

Comment: ... but this will only work for the first digit in `$argv[$i]`, because "If from and to have different lengths, the extra characters in the longer of the two are ignored." (from the manual)

Answer (score 2):

## [APL (Dyalog APL)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 9 bytes

```apl
∧/×≢¨2∩/⎕
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/apl-dyalog#rZI7DgIxDER7TpHO5eb/udBeZUNDh@hpgGvATXKRBduAEgmQyG6KiRLJfvFkSp7GueTTcDuU7fF61iVfhrLbP@6mWYzi37URAhS08tT6AG1NJ0djL21QjUW1DtV5@FLTx/HclQlMY7Jal6N4FJ1QSRwr85kpVaAdFnGs8yEmSX/BOGbIytPl87weCjQX@efaWIjVc2DeOfhR08dJEXtH8j/4Ks0fPMN1Bw)

`∧/` are all ones in the list of

`×` the signs

`≢` of the tally of

`¨` each of

`2∩/` the pair-wise intersections of

`⎕` the input?

Comment: I'm not sure what "the signs" means, but you can assume all numbers will be positive.

Comment: @Carcigenicate they can be zero too.

Comment: Yes, sorry. "Non-negative".

Answer (score 2):

## PHP, 75 bytes

```php
for($b=3**39;--$argc;)preg_replace("#[$b]#","",$b=$argv[$argc])<$b?:die(1);
```

takes numbers from command line arguments; exits with `1` for falsy, with `0` for truthy.
Run with `-r` or [test it online](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/d20de231cb3e127654740d81b4deb46b56b27ee2).

- start with `$b` = a number containing all digits
- loop down through the arguments

  - remove all digits of `$b` from the argument
  - copy argument to `$b`
  - if no digit was removed, exit with `1`
- implicit: exit with `0`

Answer (score 1):

## PHP, 77 Bytes

```
for($i=$t=1;++$i<$argc;)$t*=preg_match("#[{$argv[$i-1]}]#",$argv[$i]);echo$t;
```

Comment: Alternative: `foreach($argv as$k=>$v)$t=$k--?$t*preg_match("#[{$argv[$k]}]#",$v)):1;echo$t;`, 77 bytes (untested).

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel Heavy alternative First you must change `$k--` to `--$k` and drop one ) after that your approach should work and you must add a @ for the warning

Comment: Oh, yes, didn't notice the useless parenthesys that causss syntax errors. And I disagree about the `$k--`. I specifically used it so that $k is still 0 on the first run. And warnings are ignorable. That means the code now is 76 bytes, but still untested.

Comment: After the edit, I can confirm that `foreach($argv as$k=>$v)$t=$k--?$t*preg_match("#[{$argv[$k]}]#",$v):1;echo$t;` is working as it should. Testing with `$argv = array(1, 12, 123, 3, 34, 45, 5, 5);` displays  `1` and testing with `$argv = array(1, 12, 123, 3, 34, 45, 5, 6);` displays `0`, as expected.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel You forget that the first parameter in the is the filename.

Comment: Oh, right... I forgot about it. Fixing the code would make it look like `foreach($argv as$k=>$v)$t=$k-->1?$t*preg_match("#[{$argv[$k]}]#",$v):1;echo$t;`, increasing the size by 1 byte :/

Comment: I've fixed it, and kept the bytecount to 77: `foreach($argv as$k=>$v)$t=$k--<2||$t*preg_match("#[{$argv[$k]}]#",$v);echo$t;`

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel Or you use the `--$k` if k=0 it it not interesting cause k=1 set the true checker to 1

Comment: I don't understand :/

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel Your first approach. --$k instead of $k-- . if $k is 0 it is 0. But if $k is 1 the true variable is set to 1 so the first item in the array is not interesting . See my first comment

Answer (score 1):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 14 bytes

```
1&)"V@VX&nv@]x
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/matl#@2@oGeau5BAWoZZX5hAWW/HfXr2kqLQko1K9Vj0tMae4Uv1/tKGRsY6xiamOghGIMI4FAA)

Thanks @LuisMendo for saving a byte. Explanation:

```
1&)            % 'Pop' the first item from the input and push it on the stack.
   "       ]   % Main 'for' loop, to loop over the rest of the input.
    V            % Stringify previous (or first) iten from the input.
     @V          % Push current number, convert to string
       X&        % Intersect with stringified number already on the stack.
         nv      % Count the size of the intersection, and add it to the existing list of sizes.
           @     % Push the current number again for the intersection in the next loop. 
             x % Remove the number pushed by the last loop.
               % Else the program would end with the result on the second instead of the first position in the stack
```

Comment: You can save a byte replacing `1)VG` by `1&)` (and this avoids repeating the first number)

Comment: @LuisMendo Of course! I vaguely remembered that MATL had this functionality, but searching for "pop" (like in a queue or stack) in the spec didn't yield any results, so I thought I was mistaken.

Comment: Yes, actually it's a particular case of reference indexing. With two outputs, a reference indexing operation like `)` gives the selected values as first output, and then the remaining values as second output

Comment: @LuisMendo Clever. They should hire you MATL guys to improve MATLAB...

Comment: Haha. I do miss some of these features in MATLAB sometimes

Answer (score 1):

## [Röda](https://github.com/fergusq/roda), <s>45</s> 35 bytes

```
{[_=~`(\S*(\S)\S* (?=\S*\2))+\S+`]}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/roda#VY3dCoJAEEav3af46MpNA3d1/Qmkh/DSFZVU8iKNtCuzV7fRKIidnW84B2auZdthQoNjDL1MaR6/ClMne/qcAuYpptCSc0snVpHNi9H0d4z1MObncqhR9cwwbve2G3F7DBfzZ9LjQWQcTzQmt7HT487Gv2RG1Xc1mxeB7a31CSYkpAvXg6egfOZTp5kI8dW6kBEiKCpSBB0RQK7CU34QRg4EeVLOtokJSLjwoLY73/VEFAsjhAECfzu88jc)

This is similar to the Perl 5 solution, which is a port of the Retina solution by Martin Ender. -10 bytes thanks to @Neil.

Here's a different solution (<s>73</s> 72 bytes):

```
{[_/""]|{|x|{x|[0]()unless[not(_ in y)]else[1]}if tryPeek y}_|sum|[_=0]}
```

It's an anonymous function that pulls strings from the stream and checks that the consecutive strings contain same characters. Explanation:

```
{
    [_/""]|    /* split strings -> creates arrays of characters */
    {|x|       /* begin for loop over character arrays */
        {      /* begin if tryPeek(y) -> peeks the second item from the stream */
               /* x and y are now two consecutive character arrays */
            x| /* push characters in x to the stream */
            [0]()unless[not(_ in y)]else[1] /* pushes 0 to the stream */
                                            /* if y contains the character */
                                            /* in the stream, otherwise 1 */
        }if tryPeek y
    }_|        /* end for loop */
    sum|       /* sum all numbers in the stream */
    [_=0]      /* return true if the sum is zero */
}
```

It could possibly be golfed more...

Comment: Would it help to have a single regexp that does the whole test in one go? Something like `^(\S*(\S)\S* (?=\S*\2))+\S+$`.

Comment: @Neil That seems to work. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

## Clojure, 71 bytes

```clj
(fn[n](every?(fn[[q w]](some q w))(partition 2 1(map #(set(str %))n))))
```

An anonymous function that accepts a sequence of numbers. Returns `true`/`false`.

I like how it reads. There's definitely a few areas that can be improved upon here. My function being passed to `map` can't easily be changed so that it doesn't require the function macro, which means the entire function can't make use of the macro, which likely added some bytes. It would also be nice if I could figure out a better way of unpacking the values in the `every?` predicate.

```clj
(defn number-chain? [nums]
  (let [; Turn each number into a set of characters
        set-nums (map #(set (str %)) nums)

        ; Partition the sets into lists of neighbors
        ; [1 2 3 4] -> [[1 2] [2 3] [3 4]]
        partitioned (partition 2 1 set-nums)]

    ; Does every second neighbor contain some element of the first?
    (every?
      (fn [[l1 l2]]
        (some l1 l2))
      partitioned)))
```

Answer (score 1):

## SimpleTemplate, 124 bytes

Wow, this was a workout!

```
{@eachargv asA keyK}{@ifK}{@setR"/[",O,"]/"}{@calljoin intoR"",R}{@ifA is notmatchesR}{@return}{@/}{@/}{@setO A}{@/}{@echo1}
```

This "simply" makes a regex using the old element, showing `1` as a truthy value, or nothing otherwise.

---

**Ungolfed:**

```
{@each argv as number key K}
    {@if K}
        {@set regex "/[", old, "]/"}
        {@call join into regex "", regex}
        {@if number is not matches regex}
            {@return false}
        {@/}
    {@/}
    {@set old number}
{@/}
{@echo 1}
```

Answer (score 1):

### JavaScript (ES6), 37 bytes

```
s=>/^(.*(.).*\n(?=.*\2))+.+$/.test(s)
```

Accepts input as a string of newline-separated numbers. Based on @MartinEnder♦'s excellent Retina answer, but doing the entire test in a single regexp because it's shorter in JavaScript that way.

Answer (score 1):

## [Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/) + Unix utilities, <s>71</s> 69 bytes

```bash
sed "s/\(.*\)/<<<\1 \&\&grepx[\1]/;1s/.*g/g/;\$s/ .*//"|tr 'x
' \ |sh
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/bash#BcE9CoAwDAbQPacIIlY79CMK/mBvYtyUOopxcOjd63vFzoMrg7bBa4cYowpro016zvvbVHasYgg@IWHV2sDBA1V@H3YfOVbOdpWyzDRPNI0kQtJTP9AP)

Input is on stdin, one number per line.

Output is in the exit code: 0 for truthy, 1 for falsey.

This can probably be golfed more.

For the code above to work, there cannot be any file in the current directory whose name is a single digit.  If this isn't acceptable, replace `[\1]` in the program with `'[\1]'` (at a cost of 2 additional bytes).

Sample run (the last test case provided in the challenge):

```bash
$ echo '98
> 87
> 76
> 11
> 12
> 23' | ./digittest > /dev/null; echo $?
1
```

(1 here is falsey.)

---

How it works:

I'll demonstrate on the sample run above.

The sed command converts the input into:

```bash
grepx[98]
<<<87 &&grepx[87]
<<<76 &&grepx[76]
<<<11 &&grepx[11]
<<<12 &&grepx[12]
<<<23
```

The tr command then converts this to the string:

```bash
grep [98] <<<87 &&grep [87] <<<76 &&grep [76] <<<11 &&grep [11] <<<12 &&grep [12] <<<23
```

This string is a shell command for doing the desired operation, so I pipe that into sh and I'm done.

Comment: The file restriction is fine, although that's certainly an odd limitation.

Answer (score 1):

## [Pip](https://github.com/dloscutoff/pip), <s>12</s> 10 bytes

```
$&B@X^_MPg
```

Takes input as a series of command-line arguments. Output is a nonempty list for truthy and an empty list for falsey. [Try it online](https://tio.run/nexus/pip#@6@i5uQQERfvG5D@//9/w/@GRv@NDIz/A6EBAA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/nexus/pip#TY7LCsIwEEX3/Yq7kKK7ZJLJYyfuC6UgCKW69CPEb4830y4kA8mcM8nNMp8/7TTero/na5rf7Tvdh3XA6mGr175tHQokIEREhaZOEg9sCamOmQCpqFAWLbnzGXK4qCmX6uA5QuvsSTqLFAREqAX/5RFqb2tBycjJ/rPf2y7tBw).

#### Explanation

```
         g  List of all cmdline args
       MP   Map this function to consecutive pairs of items from that list:
     ^_      Split 1st item of pair into list of characters
    X        Convert to regex that matches any of those characters
  B@         Find all matches in 2nd item of pair
$&          Fold on logical AND--truthy if all items are truthy, falsey if one is falsey
            Print (implicit)
```

Answer (score 1):

### Q, 57 bytes

```
{r::();({r,::any(last x)in y;x,enlist y}\)($)0,x;all 1_r}
```

1. Initialises global r.
2. Converts input to array of strings.
3. Scans array checking that some character in last string is in current string.
4. Appends each result to r.
5. Returns 1 if all strings satisfy step 3 else returns 0.

Note: 0 appended to start of input array within function. This was done so that the comparison of the first element would be done enlisted. Otherwise, the last character of the first element is grabbed for comparison. Could do a type check however that adds 7 bytes over the current count.

Comment: This looks like a similar approach to my Clojure answer. Neat looking language.