# Tips for golfing in Röda

Tags: code-golf, tips

[Röda](https://github.com/fergusq/roda/) is a stream-based scripting language created by [fergusq](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/66323/fergusq).

What general tips do you have for golfing in Röda? I'm looking for ideas that can which can be applied to code-golf problems and which are also at least somewhat specific to Röda (e.g. "remove comments" is not an answer).

Please post one tip per answer.

Comment: Are you trying to get tips to beat me in the golf? :P (I should probably look at the tips for Python page)

Comment: Wow, a question from PCG.SE that got into the Hot Network Questions and is not a programming puzzle / challenge! :)

Comment: @HyperNeutrino Shhh.... :)

Answer (score 7):

## Use underscores

This is probably the most important tip. Nearly every golfed Röda program uses underscores.

The underscore syntax is syntactic sugar for `for` loops. The following lines of code are equivalent:

```
ls""|fileLength x for x|sort|pull
ls""|fileLength _|sort|pull
```

Each underscore adds a new variable to an invisible `for` loop that is around the statement. The loop pulls one value from the stream for each variable/underscore and then repeats, until no values are left.

Underscores can be used anywhere in statements:

```
a[x:y+1]=[1]*(1+y-x) /* Sets range x..y (inclusive) */
seq x,y|a[_]=1       /* 6 bytes less */
```

If you must refer to the same underscore value more than once, or use the values in reverse order, you can put a number after the underscore:

```
a|[_^_1]  /* maps x to x^x */
a|[_2-_1] /* maps each pair (x,y) to y-x, eg. [1,2,4,8] -> [1, 4] */
```

Answer (score 3):

## Some semicolons/newlines are optional

When writing Röda code, it is generally recommended to use newlines or semicolons to separate all statements. However, when golfing, it is worth to know that not all semicolons are really required.

Here's an incomplete list of places where semicolons/newlines are **optional**. Most of them do not apply when the following statement begins with an operator (`(`, `[`, `+`, etc.).

- After assignments
- After function calls, when there's at least one argument (eg. `f x`) **or** when parentheses are used (eg. `f()`)
- Everywhere, if the next line/statement would begin with `|`, `)`, `]` or `}`

If the next statement begins with an operator, the semicolon/newline is **optional** if

- The statement is a function call and parentheses are used, eg `{f(x)[y]}` is same as `{f(x);[y]}`. This works only in statement context, not when the function call is an expression.
- The statement is an assignment and parentheses are used, eg `x=(y)[z]` is same as `x=(y);[z]` (that is not same as `x=((y)[z])`).

And here are some places where the newlines are unfortunately **required**:

- After `++` and `--`.
- After `[...]`.

It is often possible to save bytes by reorganizing assignments. For example:

```
a=0;b=""c=[""]
b=""c=[b]a=0

x=f()y=i;z=a[0]
x=f()z=a[0]y=i
```

Answer (score 1):

## Use suffix control structures

It is almost **never** optimal not to use suffix statements, as you can use `{...}` in place of `do...end`.

Some examples:

```
x|unless[not(_ in y)]do[0]else[1]done
x|[0]unless[not(_ in y)]else[1]

if[p<0]do c+=p;a-=p done
{c+=p;a-=p}if[p<0]
```

Comment: Can you do `if[_ in y]` instead?

Comment: @KritixiLithos No, because I want the condition to be OR, not AND. Currently it checks if there is **at least one** value in `x` that is also in `y`, but your condition would check if **all** values in `x` are also in `y`. (The example was copied [from here](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/112937/number-chaining-predicate/112974#112974)).

Answer (score 1):

## Use the stream for input

In cases where the input is a list of elements, it can be beneficial to pull the values from the stream instead of getting them as an array.

In most of the cases the array elements are iterated by pushing them to the stream and then iterating it using a `for` loop (or an underscore). As the elements are iterated from the stream anyway, why not *define* that they should be there from the beginning?

For example, to calculate the sum of the squares of the numbers in input:

```
{|a|a|[_^2]|sum} /* Removing a redundant argument */
{[_^2]|sum}      /* saves 5 bytes */
```

Answer (score 1):

## Using ``` `` ``` strings

In `""` strings, you will have to escape certain characters in order to use them. For example, to print the backslash, you would have to have a string like `"\\"`. There is one added byte for escaping the backslash. However, if you use ``` `` ```, you do **not** have to escape this character and can save one byte.

```
print"\\"     /* 9 bytes */
print`\`      /* 8 bytes */
```

---

Not just that, you can encode variables and expressions inside of ``` `` ``` strings using `$variableName` or `${expression}`, a feature not present in `""` strings.

<sub>We are outputting the string `"a"` concatenated with the value of the variable `b` with a trailing newline in these examples.</sub>

```
["a",b,"      /* 11
"]               bytes   */
[`a$b         /* 8
`]               bytes; encodes b in the string using $b */
```

Answer (score 1):

## Use `,` instead of `and`

Conditions in Röda are streams, and can consist of multiple values. These values are reduced to one boolean value with `and`.

This means that you can replace `and` with `,` in conditions to push multiple values to the stream:

```
x if[a and b]
x if[a,b]
```

## Empty condition is truthy

It is also possible to have a condition that contains no values, which is truthy.

```
x while true
x while[]
```

Answer (score 1):

The parentheses are optional in the statement context. This applies even if the argument begins with an operator. For example, `[a()|sqrt-_]` is shorter than `[a()|sqrt(-_)]`. The parentheses after `a` are mandatory, as `a` is in the expression context, not in the statement context.

However, writing `[a()|sqrt(_+1)*2]` is not possible, and extra parentheses are needed to help the parser: `[a()|sqrt((_+1)*2)]`. Often it is possible to rewrite such expression so that it doesn't begin with a parenthesis: `[a()|sqrt 2*(_+1)]`

Comment: Is it also possible to pass multiple parameters to functions without requiring parentheses?

Comment: @KritixiLithos Yes. Eg. `[a()|atan2 _,_]` would be allowed.

Answer (score 1):

## Use `,` instead of `..` in `[]`/`push` statements

> Related: [Use `,` instead of `and`](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/114401/41805)

The `push` function (as well as the `print` function) can take any number of arguments, and outputs each one of them with no delimiter.

So that means something like this

```
["a"..b]        /*8 bytes (string "a" concatenated with variable b)*/
```

can be shortened into just

```
["a",b]         /*7 bytes*/
```

saving 1 byte.

Answer (score 1):

## `[]`/`push` > `print`

Never use `print` statements. `[]` push statements are always golfier. The difference between `print` and `push` is that the former outputs a trailing newline while the latter doesn't. However, this can be circumvented.

```
print"a"              /* 8 bytes */
["a                   /* 6 bytes; uses a literal newline */
"]

print"a",b            /* 10 bytes */
[`a$b                 /* 8 bytes; uses a literal newline and `` strings */
`]
```

Answer (score 1):

## Write replacement lists in form `*"...;..."/";"`

The `replace` function takes normally a list of strings as arguments. However, if the list is very long, it is beneficial to simply store the regex/replacement pairs in a string and then split the string and use the star operator:

```
replace"a","b","c","d"
replace*"a;b;c;d"/";"
```